# Problems Connecting to Bluetooth devices through python

Tags: python, bluetooth, python-2.x

I am trying to write a simple python script that connects any bluetooth audio device to the raspberry pi 4. I keep getting "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')"

Here is what I currently have: (uses python2)

```
import bluetooth

devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = False, flush_cache = True, duration = 20)
print devices

print bluetooth.lookup_name(devices[0])

for services in bluetooth.find_service(address = devices[0]):
    print " Name: %s" % (services["name"])
    print " Description: %s" % (services["description"])
    print " Protocol: %s" % (services["protocol"])
    print " Provider: %s" % (services["provider"])
    print " Port: %s" % (services["port"])
    print " Service id: %s" % (services["service-id"])
    print ""
    print ""

s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.connect((devices[0],1))
```

Output:

```
['E8:07:BF:35:2E:39']
TAOTRONICS SoundSurge 46
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connectTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.connect((devices[0],1))
  File "<string>", line 5, in connect
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

Occasionally when I execute the script it doesn't return any errors, but it still doesn't connect to the device. It also never prints any services.

I should also mention I am using a raspberry pi 4 and PyBluez for bluetooth control. I'm also new to raspberry pis, especially bluetooth programming so any input would be well appreciated.

Comment: When you run your script, is a code request displayed on the device you are trying to connect to?

Comment: @Ephemeral No, I am currently trying to connect to headphones

Comment: I also don't know if I am using the correct port or not.

Comment: ha ok sorry. First try to connect with `bluetoothctl`  → `[bluetooth]# connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` then `[bluetooth]# pair AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` and `[bluetooth]# trust AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`. `[bluetooth]# list` , what is the status ? (change with your BT addr)

Comment: And use `sdptool browse AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` for checking services and ports.

Comment: Why you did not try with `services["port"]`, `s.connect((devices[0],1))` would become `s.connect((devices[0], services["port"]))` in the loop ? (do conditionnal for specific device BT addr and if the device at index is your current interresting device/service?, call connect with port variable and break the loop)

Comment: I tried pairing using bluetoothctl and it worked fine. Then I went back to using my script and it worked too for some reason. A dialog box popped up asking to accpet pairing, is there any way to accept this in the script?

Comment: I tried sdptool browse (address) and it just returned "browsing (address)". Also I tried my script a few more times and it only works about 25% of the time. Sometimes it gives the dialog box, sometimes it just ends without connecting, and sometimes it returns "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')".

Comment: When you `trust` the device the device is known by blueZ and no popup is opened. (If I remember correctly). Your python script use BlueZ, so the device 'trust' is recognized.

Comment: You can also have a BT bad link , what is your RSS ?

Comment: 1. How do I trust a device?

Comment: 2. it doesnt return any services, so I can't do services["port"]

Comment: 3. How do I find my RSS?

Comment: 1- `[bluetooth]# trust AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` in python I don't know.

Comment: 2 - Then something chose is wrong.

Comment: 3 - `hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`, you can monitor in realtime with `watch -n 0.5 hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` (the ADDR is your BT adapter in this case)

Comment: "hcitool rssi AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF returns "RSSI return value: 0" after I manually connect it using the raspbian GUI.

Comment: `bluez-test-discovery` and this ? If your device use BLE : `./btmon &` and then `hcitool lescan` (try to refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417017/bluetooth-le-signal-strength-linux))

Comment: please , edit your original question with all your steps and outputs.

Comment: I tried a different bluetooth speaker, and it returns "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')"

Comment: Sometimes you need to power off and power your device (your speaker) ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be that you are trying to connect with the `RFCOMM` profile that your headphones are unlikely to support.

`s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)`

With the pydbus library it is fairly straightforward to use the BlueZ documented DBus API. The documentation for these are available at:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

Some useful things to know about DBus to get you started:

1. The Dbus service for bluez is called 'org.bluez'
2. The default Bluetooth adapter normally has '/org/bluez/hci0' as its DBus object path.
3. The DBus object path for a device is the adapter path appending with `dev_` and the mac address with the `:` replaced with `_`

This example connects to my Bluetooth speaker. It does assume it has already been paired with the Raspberry Pi

```py
import pydbus

audio_dev = '50:C9:71:67:41:CD'
adapter_path = '/org/bluez/hci0'
device_path = f'{adapter_path}/dev_{audio_dev.replace(":", "_")}'

bluez_service = 'org.bluez'
bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get(bluez_service, adapter_path)
device = bus.get(bluez_service, device_path)

device.Connect()
```